# Orchard model inheritance with Table-Per-Concrete-Type?

Tags: c#, orm, orchardcms, hibernate-mapping, table-per-class

I know that the underlying ORM used in Orchard is NHibernate and it does support the so-called `ClassMapping` which may help customize the mappings the way we want.

However I'm not sure about how Orchard utilizes the mapping methods supported by NHibernate. In this case it seems to always use the strategy similar to `Table Per Type` in EF as well as some other ORMs. With that strategy, the base class will be mapped to some common table whereas the derived class will be mapped to another table which contains all properties of its own (not declared in the base class). Those 2 tables will have a one-one relationship.

Now I really want to make it use the strategy similar to `Table Per Concrete Type` in which the base and derived classes will be mapped to 2 different tables with all properties (including inherited properties) being mapped to columns. Those 2 tables will not have any relationship, so querying for columns in just one table will not unexpectedly generate an inner JOIN (for one-one relationship).

Actually that requirement makes sense in case we just need to partition our data (from 1 big table to 2 or more small tables that have the same schema). We don't want to re-declare or use some kind of duplicate model classes (with different names), instead we just need to create a new model class and let it inherit from one base model class containing all necessary properties.

With the current code like this:

```
public class ARecord {
    //properties ...
}
public class BRecord : ARecord {
    //empty here
}
```

Currently we cannot use `BRecord` because it is understood as another part of the `ARecord`, the auto-generated query (always with INNER JOIN) will be failed because of some does-not-exist table or column names.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to like it ;) In a nutshell, the answer is don't do inheritance at all. Orchard was very deliberately designed around the idea of composition, steering well clear of inheritance in its content models. Maybe the central idea in Orchard is to make the concept of content part the "atom of content", and to design those basic units as very simple and composable pieces of functionality that do one thing well.

After all these years, the concept has held remarkably well, and I've yet to see an example of a content model where inheritance would have been more elegant and appropriate. This is reflected in the way nHibernate is customized and used in Orchard, as you've discovered.

So the solution to your problem can likely be one of two things:

1. You're modeling contents, and you should re-think your approach towards composition of parts. If you give a little more details about your specific scenario (maybe in a new question), I'm happy to help specifically in this direction.
2. You're modeling non-content data, in which case you might want to consider opting out of Orchard's specific nHibernate content-specialized idiosyncrasies and do things closer to the metal. Again, if you give more specifics about your scenario, I'm happy to take a look and give some pointers.

Comment: I think my model class is closer to what described in #2, it's not a content type. I think I've explained fairly clearly about what I want and why I want that. I can simply declare 2 classes called `ARecord` and `BRecord` without any inheritance relationship but I have to maintain the sameness between the 2 classes with all same properties (each time I add one new property to 1 class, I need to remember to add that same one to the other).It becomes more bothersome when such as I have 3 or even more classes.It would be convenient if we can use inheritance here and that's what I'm wondering for.

Comment: the main idea is to partition data into some small tables (for better performance when querying) instead of putting all in one big table using some discriminator column (as similar to Table-Per-Hierarchy paradigm).

Comment: Yeah, so as I said, in that case, you should not use Orchard's nHibernate integration, which is very specialized for its own content type system, and which only get in the way. You can opt out of the Orchard ambient transaction by putting code into a `using(new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress)) {...}` block.

Comment: I would like to still take advantage of the `IRepository` and of course the ambient transaction provided by Orchard, not sure why you suggested using custom transaction scope? I don't think what I want has anything conflicted with the Orchard system design, I can always end up using 2 same classes and actually I'm going that way, trying to avoid as much duplicate code as possible.

Comment: I suggested it because it is sometimes useful in similar scenarios. I was also suggesting that maybe your problem could be solved from a different angle that is more in tune with the conventions in place in Orchard, but it seems like you're set on inheritance, so I'm afraid my answer is not helping. I can remove it if you want. Your question seems to be more about nHibernate than Orchard, and I assume you've already googled "nhibernate table-per-concrete type". If so, it would be useful to update your question with what you've tried and how it didn't work.

Comment: Yes it's more related to NHibernate but I could not easily find the mapping code in Orchard framework so that I can modify it the way I want. Also it would be better if we can modify it via some middleware (injection) without polluting the framework code. You can keep your answer if you want. As I said I've already chosen to use 2 different classes without any inheritance. Thanks for your help anyway 

Comment: Yeah, that's because it's not particularly designed to be modified. Orchard 1.x was designed as an extensible content management application, and nHibernate was almost an implementation detail rather than one of the features to be extended. You may actually have more chance with Orchard Core, which is designed as both a set of useful libraries and as a CMS built on that framework. That means that you get more leeway on the design of the part of your application that is not content, and how much you decide to take in. Its data access is very different however, as it's heavily document-oriented.